# How to create SPs, Tables, Functions and Triggers

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm currently working on application where one of the requirements is the ability to create SP, Tables, Functions, Triggers, etc. from inside ASP.NET. The language I'm using is C# but I don't know if this is even possible. Would you mind pointing me to the right direction or provide me with some code examples?

I tried looking online but I'm unable to find any information regarding this.

@rmayer06, I followed your advice and below is my code:

```
protected void createproc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sqlscript = File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/sp_create.sql"));

    try
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlscript, con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TCKT"].ConnectionString;

        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("An error has occurred" + ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: One way of doing this is building dynamic queries and DDL statements using data you have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be possible using `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()`, or by using the classes in `Microsoft.SqlServer` namespace.  I found this in a quick search: http://forums.asp.net/t/1703608.aspx/1

However, I would ask for additional clarification on your requirements if I were you.  It seems odd that you would need to create SPs dynamically; generally, it is better to design them as part of the database if they are needed, as SPs will need to be optimized, debugged, etc.

On a related note, I have run database update scripts from within c#, which did create stored procedures as part of updating the database code.  If that is what you are doing, I recommend the following:

1. Script your entire database to a single `.SQL` file.
2. Use the sqlcmd utility to execute the file against your local server. This can be done by calling `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()` from the web application and supplying the necessary command-line parameters.

As a caveat, your web app process will need permissions to launch the sqlcmd process.  Or as an alternative, you can use the `SqlCommand` class and just dump the entire contents of your SQL script into a string, which you pass to the command.  I think I've done that too, and it worked.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This will only be necessary on first installation of the application. Also, would you mind providing some examples on the Microsoft.SqlServer namespace?

Comment: So, you are doing the initial database creation?

Comment: Right, just give my suggestion a try and see what happens. It should work. Save the SQL script in the project as either (a) an embedded resource (search for how to get those back out) or (b) a compile-include file so it gets into the bin folder.

Comment: Understand, thank you for your help. Currently working on option (a)

Comment: this is what I did. I create a script file with all the SP, Tables, Triggers, etc. I then loaded the entire file into a string and run the SqlCommand based on that string and it created all my SPs, Tables, Triggers, etc. Thank you very much for your help.